# How to read the last n values from a binary file in R or python?

Tags: python, r

How do you read in the last n values from a binary file in either R or python?

Comment: What have you tried, and how did it come up short?

Comment: Hi Scott, In R I tried dat = readBin(files[f], n=3e7, what='integer', endian='swap'), but specifying n only gives you the first values in the binary file. In python I tried using the array and struct libraries to import the binary file, but specifying n also only gives you the first n values instead of the last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do it this way you are still buffering the file in; however, you're not keeping the entire file in memory just to get the final few bytes. Only significant for large files of course.

```
>>> fileName = 'temp.py'
>>> from os.path import getsize
>>> size = getsize(fileName)
>>> n = 10
>>> with open('temp.py', 'rb') as temp:
...     temp.seek(size - 10)
...     temp.read()
...     
207
b'bUrl+term)'
```

Answer (score 0):

In python3 it's as simple as:

```
bytes_read = open("filename", "rb").read()
last_n_bytes = bytes_read[-n:]
```

Python uses slice notation, so we can slice the byte array by going: start at the nth from last character (`-n`), then get all characters (`:`), and since we don't provide an end value it just goes to the end.

In R (which I'm not 100% sure on), you should be able to read in the file:

```
dat = readBin(files[f], n=3e7, what='integer', endian='swap')
```

(You might need a large value of `n` to grab the whole file).

After that you can use `tail` on resulting vector (`dat`):

```
dat = tail(dat,n)
```

If your file is too large to be stored in memory, let me know, I can suggest alternate solutions.

Comment: You can check the file size with `file.size`.